# How to extract the values from a raster in R

Tags: r, extract, raster

I want to use R to extract values from a raster. Basically, my raster has values from 0-6 and I want to extract for every single pixel the corresponding value. So that I have at the end a data table containing those two variables.

Thank you for your help, I hope my explanations are precisely enough.

Comment: have you tried this?[Extract data from a Raster object for the locations of other spatial data](https://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/raster/html/extract.html)

Comment: Did you try things? Try `vignette('Raster')` for example

Comment: @sera, I already found this tutorial but I am quite confused about what you actually have to use for the extraction.

Comment: maybe see here that has examples [Example 1](http://neondataskills.org/R/crop-extract-raster-data-R/) [Example 2](http://neondataskills.org/R/Raster-Data-In-R/)

Comment: @sera, I understand the steps in the Example 1 tutorial. I loaded my raster in R and then I tried to extract my values with the extract() function. Due to the reason that I am not using an AOI, like in the tutorial I am confused now with the x and y values. I tried this with the function: values_raster <- extract(x = values, df=TRUE) but this is not working.

Comment: @JCra the x should be the raster object and the y should be a vector (representing cell numbers) in your case

Comment: Just to get sure, the x is the whole raster or just the object I want to extract, in my case the values? For the y is it possible to use a point shapefile, as I want to compare my extracted values with those points later on?

Comment: @JCra x is the whole raster and y can be an object depending on what you want to extract. for x and y please read here [link](https://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/raster/html/extract.html) in the section "Details"

Answer (score 6):

Example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=5, nrow=5, vals=1:25)
```

To get *all* values, you can do

```
values(r)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
#as.matrix(r)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#[2,]    6    7    8    9   10
#[3,]   11   12   13   14   15
#[4,]   16   17   18   19   20
#[5,]   21   22   23   24   25
```

Also see `?getValues`

You can also use indexing

```
r[2,2] 
#7 
r[7:8]
#[1] 7 8
```

For more complex extractions using points, lines or polygons, see `?extract`

Answer (score 1):

x is the `raster` object you are trying to extract values from; y is may be a SpatialPoints, SpatialPolygons,SpatialLines, Extent or a vector representing cell numbers (take a look at `?extract`). Your code `values_raster <- extract(x = values, df=TRUE)` will not work because you're feeding the function with any y object/vector. 
You could try to build a vector with all cell numbers of your raster. Imagine your raster have 200 cells. If your do `values_raster <- extract(x = values,y=seq(1,200,1), df=TRUE)` you'll get a dataframe with values for each cell.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply doing

```
as.data.frame(s, xy=TRUE) # s is your raster file
```